# Google Sign Up code not working

Tags: php, google-signin

I am using google sign up for my web application. In my server I've accomplished google sign up successfully. But when I moved my application to another server the page which contains the google sign up code is not working. When I load that page, a blank white page appears. I couldn't understand what exactly happened also there is no syntactic errors in my code.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<p>Google</p>
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include("db.php");
require_once 'google-login-api/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-login-api/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
$google_client_id       = 'client id'; //my client id
$google_client_secret   = 'client secret'; //my client secret
$google_redirect_url    = 'Redirect url'; // my redirect url
$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

if (isset($_REQUEST['reset'])) 
{
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
  $gClient->revokeToken();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)); //redirect user back to page
}


if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{ 
$gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
return;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{ 
$gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) 
{
  $user                 = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
  $user_id              = $user['id'];
  $user_name            = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $email                = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $profile_url          = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  $profile_image_url    = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
  $personMarkup         = "$email<div><img src='$profile_image_url?sz=50'></div>";
  $_SESSION['token']    = $gClient->getAccessToken();
}
else 
{
$authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
<p>Google One</p>
</html>
```

When i run this page, only the text inside first paragraph displays that is **Google**

Can anyone help me to find whats the actual problem with my code..??

Comment: have you checked the error log?

Comment: Yeah.. I've checked the error log. I found This error in the log **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension' in /var/www/developer/google-login-api/src/Google_Client.php:21\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/developer/indextest.php(6): require_once()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/developer/google-login-api/src/Google_Client.php on line 21**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is stated in the error message:

> Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension

You need to check that you have curl installed on your server, and if it is there, you need to recompile PHP so it knows that curl is there.

Without knowing what kind of server you're on and what access permissions you have, it's almost impossible to advise a course of action. Here are some general instructions, though:

[Instructions for curl installation and compiling php with curl support](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php)

[Using phpinfo to check your system setup](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)